# Load file in a div using POST method

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have already loaded a bootstrap modal on post method, now the modal contains user post comments and a form from where the admin can also make a comments/reply to post. Below is the attached image

[image]

Now when the admin post comment the popup should reload only using **Post** method, it works if i load it using **GET**, by sinply changing my route, but i want to load using POST. Here is the code that I am using for ajax.

```
function comment() {
    jQuery('#showModal').on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var propertyID = jQuery('#propertyID').val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': jQuery('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            url: '/user/Property/postComment',
            type: 'POST',
            data: new FormData(this),
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            timeout: 10000,
            beforeSend: function () {
                jQuery('#commentBtn').html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                // jQuery('#showModal').load('/user/loadPropertyComments/'+propertyID);
                jQuery('.result').show();
                jQuery('.result').html(data);
                jQuery('#commentBtn').html('Post Comment');
            },
            error: function (data) {
                jQuery('.result').show();
                jQuery('.result').html(data);
                jQuery('#commentBtn').html('Post Comment');
            }
        });
    });
} jQuery(comment());
```

I gives console error, if i try to load using POST method, **says method not allowed**. How can i convert it into POST, any idea.

Comment: Your response says post not allowed?  Does your router allow post for that endpoint?

Comment: Route::post('/user/loadPropertyComments/{property_id}', 'back\Property@loadPropertyComments'); this is my route now it loads using post method but jquery.load method loads using GET

Comment: Neither of those match your url. `'/user/Property/postComment'`

Comment: request does goes to this method but the issue is that GET request is being sent, if you check on jquery.load function it works on get method i want to override this method to post, if that is possible my problem will be solved

Comment: load is just a get that then puts the returned data in the element.  if you do that same logic as a post it should be fine.  So long as your endpoint is setup to accept that request.  And given the route you provided I'm not seeing how it would match either of those.